# Problema con annotations @BeforeTest @AfterTest en testing automatizado

Tags: eclipse, selenium, annotation

estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Selenium con Eclipse para la automatización de pruebas. Al intentar ejecutar annotations me devuelve el error:

> the annotation “X” is disallowed for this location.

Como estoy empezando con el tema igual me estoy dejando algo importante en el tintero.

```
package TestNG;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@BeforeTest
public void login() {
    System.out.println("BT");
}

@AfterTest
public void logout{
    System.out.println("AT");
}

public class TestNGClass {
    @Test 
    public void testContact(){
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }
}
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con el error? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola L.Arena . Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes mostrar tu codigo para ver como lo estás haciendo?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu publicacion. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. No lo había puesto porque es un código de prueba para trastear el funcionamiento de las annotations, pero si me atasco ahí poco podré avanzar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Los metodos @Before y @After deben estar dentro de una clase tambien.

Despues de esto las anotaciones deben funcionar correctamente antes de los metodos:

```
public class ProjectWebAnnotations {
@BeforeTest
public void startTest(final ITestContext testContext) {}

@BeforeMethod
public void openDriver() {}

@AfterMethod
public void closeDriver() {}
}
```